# How do I detect whether the site view is mobile or desktop in order to hide my custom overlay scrollbar when the mobile gray scroll bar is present?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, scrollbar

So I am using this plugin tool https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/ to add a custom overlay scroll bar to my site. The reason being is to take the gutter away from the default scrollbar to not cause interference with some of my other elements. That goal was accomplished and it looks great but I noticed in mobile view on my Android phone it is present along with the default gray scrollbar that disappears after a moment when not scrolling and is present on every site I browse on my phone. This gray scrollbar is also present when I go into dev tools on my desktop and toggle the device toolbar to see at mobile view. Basically, the problem is that I have two scrollbars on mobile and I think it looks bad and would like to remove the custom one when the gray one becomes active.

I have not shared code or anything because it is really straightforward what I have done to set it up and I have not done any custom tweaks to it. The link I sent contains the instructions and all I have done is attached the style sheet and script for the plug-in to my page, and then I have added to my own script the default variable it listed in the steps

```
var { 
OverlayScrollbars, 
ScrollbarsHidingPlugin, 
SizeObserverPlugin, 
ClickScrollPlugin  
} = OverlayScrollbarsGlobal;
```

and then after that, I added another line to my script which initializes the plug-in onto the element that I want it on, which in this case is the body so

```
const osInstance = OverlayScrollbars(document.body, {});
```

That's all I did to get it to work, the other reason I'm not showing code is that I don't feel my issue is directly related to the plug-in and removing it when certain conditions are met and has more to do with understanding of the gray default mobile scrollbar in order to figure out my best approach because I actually had two ideas for how to go about this. 1. was to set in my Javascript that when the screen reaches below a certain size to deinitialize the plugin it from the body element. 2. Was to use CSS and set a media query that when below a certain screen size it would "display: none;" the scroll bar plug-in.

The issue is several things I don't understand. Is this gray scrollbar across all browsers or is it just for Chrome? I've tried googling for that but no answers. At what screen size does it kick in? Once again couldn't find any answers for that and without a screen size to go by to turn off the plug-in my two approaches are dead in the water.

The weird thing is that in the chrome dev tools on the device toolbar view, this gray scrollbar is present on not just in mobile view but if I size up the page while in that toolbar view its still there even at desktop size. Like for example if I go into device tool bar view and make the site width to be 600px it still shows the gray scroll bar but if I exit the device toolbar view and size my browser window to 600px its not there. This leads me to believe that this gray bar is kicking in with some sort of status that's telling it whether the view is mobile or desktop regardless of what the screen size is. If that is the case and I'm purely speculating, then all I would need to do is set my plug-in scrollbar to "display: none;", or deinitailize it from the body when that status is on.

Would appreciate any help understanding this gray scrollbar.